# How can I get my iPad to automatically connect to my iPhone's hotspot?

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi, tethering

I have a Wi-Fi iPad. Every time I turn it on, I want it to automatically connect to my phone’s Internet.

Right now what I have to do is go into settings, then Wi-Fi, then select my phone. Is there a way to automatically have it connect?

Comment: Hmm. Try this: Name your hotspot “AAAAAA”.  Connect to it and make sure “Auto-Join” is switched on in the details menu of the networked accessed by pressing the “i” next to the network name.

Comment: @JBis how do I change my hotspot name? It’s automatically set to the name of my iPhone. And iPhone hotspots don’t get tied “i.” Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your hotspot name is based on your iPhone name which can be changed in Settings>General>About>Name

Comment: For all wondering, my idea behind this is that the iPhone priorities SSIDs based on Alphabetical order. This will put the hotspot at the top of the priority list.

Comment: Connect manually. Then:
System Preferences > Network > 
Select the WiFi hotspot name and check the Automatic Connect radio button.

Answer (score 11):

To get that feature, you need to **"Set up Instant Hotspot"** which is part of Apple's [Continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204681) feature.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204681#hotspot

> Use Instant Hotspot with any Mac, iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch that
>   meets the [Continuity system requirements](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204689). It works when your
>   devices are near each other and set up as follows:
>
> - Your iPhone or iPad (Wi-Fi + Cellular) has an activated carrier plan    providing [Personal Hotspot](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203302) service.
> - Each device is [signed in to iCloud with the same Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204053).
> - Each device has Bluetooth turned on.
> - Each device has Wi-Fi turned on.

Comment: Make sure that your device meets the system requirements and is signed in to the same Apple ID and that you use on both devices. Lastly both Bluetooth and Wifi need to be on.

Comment: Thanks, Melvin. That’s what I’m trying to avoid. Every time I get started, I have to go into WiFi settings and connect to my iPhone. I’m trying to have it automatically connect. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes make sure both devices have Wifi and Bluetooth turned on. They dont need to be connected but make sure they are on, then if both devices are using the same Apple ID, make sure they both are on at least iOS 8. Then it should auto connect.

Comment: Melvin, Instant Hotspot is a way to rapidly connect 2 Apple products using the same iCloud account for Wi-Fi tethering but it always requires an action from the user (clicking the "Connect to xxx" in Wi-Fi settings). So as far as I know Instant Hotspot is not an automatic process as for instance it doesn’t reconnect automatically after a disconnection.

Comment: Actually it is automatic. All it requires is that both devices are near each other and have wifi and bluetooth turned on along with the correct software version. I use it with my iPad. Everytime my iPhone comes near it with wifi and bluetooth on it automatically connects. I turn off bluetooth on my iPad to use my home wifi.

Comment: This doesn’t work for my iphone/ipad. Not only do i have to go in to the Wifi settigns each time, I also need several attempts before it works. It os annoying. My ipad will automatically connect to my wife’s android phone, but not to my iphone.

Comment: Are they using the same software version @KristvanBesien?

Comment: They all are on the latest version.

Comment: Backup your iPhone (iCloud or iTunes)  and then go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings. If that doesn't work then try Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings (this one doesn't reset the entire phone just the settings application and everything it controls). It appears to be device-specific. If it doesn't work after that, then call Apple Support so they can gather some device logs from the iPhone and iPad.